# How to make sure that foreach loop data shows in correct set position views

Tags: codeigniter

I have a controller that shows modules for my each position

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [layout_module_id] => 1
            [layout_id] => 1
            [module_id] => 1
            [position] => column_left
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [layout_module_id] => 2
            [layout_id] => 1
            [module_id] => 2
            [position] => column_left
            [sort_order] => 2
        )

)
```

Above currently I have only two modules set and the are in the position of column left.

Because the position views are out side of the foreach loop they are picking up that module even though not set for that position? As shown in image.

[image]

[image]

> **Question:** How can I make sure that the module will only display in its set position view.

```
public function index() {
    $layout_id = $this->getlayoutID($this->router->class);

    $modules = $this->getlayoutsmodule($layout_id);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($modules);
    echo "</pre>";

    $data['modules'] = array();

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $this->load->library('module/question_help');
        $data['modules'][] = $this->load->view('module/question_help', $this->question_help->set(), TRUE);  
    }

    // Position Views
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->view('column_left', $data, TRUE);
    $data['column_right'] = $this->load->view('column_right', $data, TRUE);
    $data['content_top'] = $this->load->view('content_top', $data, TRUE);
    $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->view('content_bottom', $data, TRUE);

    // Main view
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}

public function getlayoutsmodule($layout_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('layouts_module');
    $this->db->where('layout_id', $layout_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }   
}
```

Each of the position views have the same foreach loop

```
<?php if ($modules) { ?>
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
<?php echo $module;?>
<?php } ?>  
<?php }?>
```

main view

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $column_left; ?>

    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
    <?php echo $content_top; ?>
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

    <div id="body">
    <p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>

    <p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
    <code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>

    <p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
    <code>application/controllers/Welcome.php</code>

    <p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>

    <?php echo $content_bottom; ?>  
    </div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the code for your views?

Comment: So you want each view to display all the data generated in the for loop or just the data generated for its corresponding position? Because your view displays all of the array items.

Comment: And will you be needing those generated values in the welcome view or will you just be accessing just the position specific views passed?

Comment: @inarilo added my main view

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this (not sure if the library needs to be loaded in each iteration but leaving it there):

```
$tmpdata = array();
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $this->load->library('module/question_help');
    $tmpdata[$module['position']]['modules'][] = $this->load->view('module/question_help', $this->question_help->set(), TRUE);
}

$data = array();
foreach ($tmpdata as $pos => $mods) {
    $data[$pos] = $this->load->view($pos, $tmpdata[$pos], TRUE);
}

$this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
```

Passing `$tmpdata[$pos]` to each position's view makes the array called `$modules` available, so in the views, just use

```
if ($modules) {
    foreach ($modules as $module) {
      echo $module;
    }  
}
```

as before.

This keeps it dynamic and you don't have to modify this code if you change or add positions. I'm using two data arrays just to avoid passing unnecessary data.

Comment: I will try your way let you know during the week.

Comment: I did a test if a position is not set in database it throws error now. Undefined variable: column_right how can I make sure if a position is not in database then will not show that error?

Comment: It appears to be treating column_right as a variable? Can you tell me which line in the above throws this error? If you want to completely leave out rows that do not have position set, you can use a WHERE condition in your sql to check for `IS NOT NULL` or `<> ''` (depending on how you are storing values).

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I've edited my answer for clarity. It is my guess that you are using the position name as a variable in the views. You should be using `$modules`.